# VHDL test bench for input port assignment

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, testbench

I am trying to depict port 3 of microcontroller which acts a I/O and as special functions like timers interrupts in VHDL.

The code is as follows:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity testIO is 
    port (
    p3: inout std_logic;
    op:out std_logic;
    r0:in std_logic;
    sel_line:in std_logic;
    T0:out std_logic;
    Clk    :  in std_logic;
    ip:in std_logic
    );
    end testIO;
    architecture beh of testIO is
    Begin
    process(clk)
    begin
    if Clk'event and Clk='1'then
    if r0 = '1' then
    T0 <= p3;
    else
    p3 <= 'Z';
    end if;             
    if sel_line = '1' and r0 = '0' then
    p3 <= ip;
    else
    p3 <= 'Z';
    end if; 
    if sel_line = '0' and r0 = '0' then
    op<= p3 ;
    else
    p3 <= 'Z';
    end if; 
    end if;
    end process;
    end beh;
```

My testbench is as follows:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    entity testIO_tb is
    end testIO_tb;
    architecture Behavioral_tb of testIO_tb is
    component testIO is
    port (
    p3: inout std_logic;
    op:out std_logic;
    r0:in std_logic;
    sel_line:in std_logic;
    T0:out std_logic;
    Clk    :  in std_logic;
    ip:in std_logic
    );
    end component;
    signal p3_s,sel_line_s,T0_s,ip_s,op_s: std_logic;
    signal r0_s:std_logic:='1';
    signal Clk_s:std_logic:='0';
    begin
    DUT1:testIO port map(
    p3   => p3_s,
    op   => op_s,
    r0   => r0_s,
    sel_line => sel_line_s,
    T0   => T0_s,
    Clk   => Clk_s,
    ip   => ip_s
    );
    Clk_s <= not Clk_s after 5ns;
    process
    begin
    if r0_s='1' then
    p3_s<='1';
    else
    p3_s<='Z';
    end if;
    wait for 10ns;
    r0_s<='0';
    sel_line_s<='1';
    ip_s<='0';
    p3_s<='Z';
    wait for 10ns;
    sel_line_s<='0';
    wait for 10ns;      
    end process;
    end Behavioral_tb;
```

In the simulation,the value of p3 is not set to '1' at 0ns though I am setting it to 1 in testbench. It is setting to 1 at 5ns.  I am not sure why.

Also T0 value is not getting updated at 5ns and ip value is not copied to p3 at 15ns.

Comment: Please format the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

To your question why p3 is not set at 0ns:
Your process in testIO is assigning values at the rising_edge of clk. What do you have at 0ns? No rising edge. So it's undefined what p3 is at the beginning. Look up some vhdl samples and have a look for reset behaviour.

If you look at testIO:

1. You check if r0 = '1' => T0 <= p3
2. You check if sel_line = '1' and r0 = '0' => p3 <= ip else p3 <= 'Z'
3. You check if sel_line = '0' and r0 = '0' => op <= p3 else p3 <= 'Z'

You see what happens here? You assign p3 in multiple paths at the same time. Look at your compiler messages.

So... I would recommend you, to make a truth table and create your logic based on this. You can assign your p3 with one if elsif else statement and not with multiple if else statements to prevent missbehaviour.

Comment: As mentioned by you I made a truth table and implemented the code. It worked as expected. Thank you!